# Prove this map is not an open map

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations

> Let $K$ be the space of bounded, continuous real-valued functions $f$ from $(0, 1) \to \Bbb R$. Let $K$ have the supremum norm. Let $L: K \to K$ be defined by $L(f)(x) = x f(x)$. Show that $L$ is not an open map (counter-examples are fine).

So I have to find an open neighborhood $N$ of $f(x) \in K$ such that the image $xf(x)$ of this neighborhood $N$ is not open. The problem is, I don't understand what it means for a neighborhood of functions to be open. I think what it means for a set of functions to be closed is that if a sequence of functions converges, then the function that the sequence of functions converges to is in that set. But unsure what the analagous definition of "open" would be.

Comment: Being open in a set of functions equipped with a norm is being open with respect to the topology induced by the norm, i.e. for every point of the set, there exists an open ball centered at this point and contained in the set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $B_R=\{f\in K : \|\,f\|<R\}$. If $K$ were open, then $L(B_1)$ would be open, and as $0\in L(B_1)$, there would exist an $r>0$, such that $B_r\subset L(B_1)$.

Observe that, if $f\in L(B_1)$, then $\,f(x)=xg(x)$, for some continuous $g$ with $\lvert g(x)\rvert <1$, for all $x$. Hence 
$$
\lvert\, f(x)\rvert=\lvert xg(x)\rvert=x\lvert g(x)\rvert <x,\quad \text{for all $x\in(0,1)$}. \tag{1}
$$
If $B_r\subset L(B_1)$, for some $r>0$, then the constant function $h(x)=r/2\in B_r$. But $h\not\in L(B_1)$, as $h$
does not satisfy $(1)$.

Comment: I have a few questions. 1) Why does it suffice to show that $L(B_1)$ does not contain an open ball with center $0$? We want to show that $L(B_1)$ is not an open set, but I don't understand why if $L(B_1)$ does not contain an open ball with center $0$, it implies that $L(B_1)$ is not open. 2) Why does $h(x) = r/2$ contradict the fact that $|f(x) < x|$? Thank you.

Comment: @morphic If $L$ were open, then $L(B_1)$ would be open, and as $0\in L(B_1)$, then there would be an $r>0$, such that $B_r\subset L(B_1)$. Now if $f\in B_r\subset L(B_1)$, then  $\lvert f(x)\rvert<x$. but $h(x)=r/2\in B_r$ and $\lvert h(x)\rvert$ is not less than $x$.

Comment: Oh, $|h(x)|$ must be less than $x$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$, and since $r/2$ is a fixed number in $(0,1)$, it is not less than all $x \in (0, 1)$?

Comment: If $x\in (0,r/2)$, then $\lvert h(x)\rvert <r/2$. Thus, the constant function $g\equiv r/2$ does not belong to $L(B_1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I have read this answer for an hour and I still don't follow. We have some arbitrary constant function $h(x) = r/2$. This function is contained in some neighborhood $B_r \subset L(B_1)$. But every function $h \in L(B_1)$ has the property that $|h(x)| < x$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$. The claim is that $r/2$ is not less than $x$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. Say for example $r = 1/2$. Then the claim is that $1/4$ is not less than $x$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$. $1/4$ is not less than $1/8$, so this is a contradiction?

Comment: I have edited my answer. It is more analytic now.

Comment: Ok, in your answer, it says that $h$ does not satisfy $(1)$. That means $$|h(x)| = r/2 = |xg(x)| = x|g(x)| \geq x$$ for some $x \in (0, 1)$. So $r/2 \geq x$ for some $x \in (0,1)$. So $r \geq 2x$ for some $x \in (0,1)$. If I can prove this inequality, then that means $h \not\in L(B_1)$. Can I just choose such an $x$ such that it makes this inequality true?

Comment: For every $r>0$, it is clear that $r/2>x$, when $x\in (0,r/2)$. Hence the constant function $h(x)=r/2$ DOES NOT belong to $L(B_1)$, for every $r>0$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't really follow. If we take an example $h(x) = 6$ to be the constant function, then we want to show that is no such $r$ such that $B_r \subset L(B_1)$. $h(x) = 6$ is in $B_{7}$, but $h(x) = 6$ is not in $L(B_1)$ because $6 > x$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$. Is this a valid counter-example to the problem?

Comment: Try to understand the following: $L(B_1)$ DOES NOT CONTAIN any constant function, while $B_r$ contains the constant function $h(x)=r/2$.

Comment: Ok, so say $B_r \subset L(B_1)$. $B_r$ contains the constant function $h(x) = r/2$ because $r/2 < r$. But $h(x) = r/2$ cannot be in $L(B_1)$ because of some reason I can't understand. If $h(x) \in L(B_1)$, then $|h(x)| < x$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$. That means $r/2 < x$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$. This is a contradiction, but I don't see why. It depends on what $r$ is. If $r > 2$, then it cannot be less than $x$ because the supremum of $x$ is $1$. If $r = 1$, then $1/2 < x$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$ is false since $1/2 < 1/4 \in (0,1)$ is a false statement. So we can always find an $x$ like this?